# Speed-up Python loop running by rows and elements in each row

Tags: python, loops, vectorization, rows

I have a dataframe containing dates as rows and columns as $investment in each stock on a particular day ("ndate"). Also, I have a Series ("portT") containing the sum of the total investments in all stocks each date (series size: len(ndate)*1). Here is the code that calculates the weight of each stock/each date by dividing each element of each row of ndate by sum of that day:

```
(l,w)=port1.shape  
for i in range(0,l):      
    port1.iloc[i]=np.divide(ndate.iloc[i],portT.iloc[i])
```

The code works very slowly, could you please let me know how I can modify and speed it up? I tried to do this by vectorising, but did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

as this is justa  simple divison of two dataframes of the same shape (or you can formulate it as such) you can use the simple `/`-operator, pandas will execute it element-wise (possibly with replication if shapes don't match, so be sure about that):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2,2], [3,3]])
df_new = df1 / df2
#>>> pd.DataFrame([[0.5, 1.],[1., 1.3]])
```

this is most likely internally doing the same operations that you have specified in your example, however, internal assignments and checks are by-passed, which should give you some speed

EDIT:
I was mistaken on the outline of your problem; maybe include a minimal self-contained code example next time. Still the `/`-operator also works for Dataframes and Series in combination:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]])
s = pd.Series([1,2])
new_df = df / s
#>>> pd.DataFrame([[1., 3.],[1., 2]])
```

Comment: Hi, please note that I take the sum (df2) from the series, not from the dataframe of the same size.